# If a photo is imported to Aperture via Photo Stream, is it safe to delete it from iCloud?

Tags: aperture

Still using Aperture to automatically import iPhone photos via My Photo Stream. But my iCloud account is almost full because of too many photos there. Is it safe to delete photos from iCloud without losing them from Aperture? In other words, once downloaded to Aperture, deleting from iCloud will not delete them from Aperture, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Aperture information tools to check where an image is stored.
See the Info tab for a given picture and if needed add the "file path" field to your Info template (using metadata presentation personalization dialog, shortcut cmd+J on my Mac)
If it says iCloud, you're wrong.